# webpack not getting the same names with output `build` folder, getting number values instead

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

I am trying to config `webpack` build with same name for my javascript and css files in to the `build` folder. but unable to get it. any one help me to fix this?

here is my config:

```
const HtmlPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    output:{
        path:path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js', //but not getting
        publicPath: ''
    },
    resolve:{
        extensions:[".ts",".tsx",".js",".jsx"]
    },
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude:/node_modules/,
                use:[{loader:"babel-loader"}]
            },
            {
                test:/\.html$/,
                use:[{loader:"html-loader"}]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: [ {loader: "file-loader",  options: {
                    name: '[path][name].[ext]'
                }}]
            },
            {
                test:/\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use:[MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins:[
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new HtmlPlugin({
            filename:"index.html",
            template:"./src/index.html"
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            "process.env":{
                "NODE_ENV":JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    devServer:{
        historyApiFallback:true,
        port:5000
    }
}
```

**"webpack": "^5.11.0",    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",** - my versions now

at present I am getting the file names like:

[image: now generate like this:]

Comment: This isn't related to your question, but you should replace your `file-loader` with the new [Asset Modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) now that you're on Webpack 5.

Comment: @Coderer - thanks for the info. actually what is the change do i required? any suggestion /tutorial /sample - webpack intro not such clear

Comment: The docs I linked to explain it pretty well.  Near the beginning is a list of the different `type: "asset"` variants and which kind of basic loader that type corresponds to.  So, you'd replace `use: "file-loader"` with `type: "asset/resource"`.  There's a lot more in the docs to address specific use cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you code splitting ?, because if you are then you have to something like this

```
import("./templates/foo" /* webpackChunkName: "chunk-foo" */ ).then(function(foo) {
    console.log('foo:', foo);
})
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/tree/master/examples/code-splitting-specify-chunk-name

or if you can tell how are you creating chunks ?, it will be helpful to understand

Comment: I am lazy loading multiple modules(using import ). if you required any details let me know

Comment: if you are using import then above example which i gave should work

Answer (score 0):

you is missing `chunkFileName` at yow `output` section, try it like this

```js
output: {
     
      filename: isProduction ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js" : "static/js/bundle.js",

      futureEmitAssets: true,

      chunkFilename: isProduction
        ? "static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js"
        : "static/js/[name].chunk.js",

      publicPath: "/",

      devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: isProduction
        ? (info) => path.relative("./src/index.js", info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")
        : ((info) => path.resolve(info.absoluteResourcePath).replace(/\\/g, "/")),

      jsonpFunction: "name-of-yow-app",

      globalObject: "this",
    },
```

Comment: getting an error as : `ReferenceError: isProduction is not defined`

Comment: sorry for that. you need to create a variable `const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV ==="production"`

Comment: error again: ` Error: Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename static/js/bundle.js (chunks 179 and 666)`